# Unicode Escape Error in timeit module python

Tags: python, timeit

I am currently using `timeit` inbuilt library of python for getting execution time of small snippets of code.

My Code:-

```
import timeit

print(timeit.timeit(setup='env = "C:\\Users\\MyName"', stmt='a = f"{env} is my username"'))
```

The above code Upon execution produces `Unicode Escape Error`.

Error Stack:-

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:/Users/apple/vul.py", line 3, in <module>
    print(timeit.timeit(setup='env = "C:\\Users\\MyName"', stmt='a = f"{env} is my username"'))
  File "C:\Users\apple\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\timeit.py", line 232, in timeit
    return Timer(stmt, setup, timer, globals).timeit(number)
  File "C:\Users\apple\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\timeit.py", line 109, in __init__
    compile(setup, dummy_src_name, "exec")
  File "<timeit-src>", line 1
SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 2-3: truncated \UXXXXXXXX escape
```

This error in general is produced when there is an Escape sequence interpretation inside a string (via a single `\` followed by a character). But in my case I have already Escaped the backslash inside the string using `\\`(double backslashes).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have correctly diagnosed the problem: an escape sequence interpretation inside a string.

You have escaped the backslash once. That means that `timeit` receives in its `setup` parameter the following string: `'env = "C:\Users\MyName"'` with one single `\` on every occurence. And when it executes the string, it finds what it sees as an offending Unicode sequence :`'\Users'`.

It is easy to fix:

```
print(timeit.timeit(setup=r'env = "C:\\Users\\MyName"', stmt='a = f"{env} is my username"'))
```

Comment: @VasuDeo.S: You have put the `r` before the `"C:\\Users..."` while I had put it before `'end = ...'`. Both do the same: a second escape level.